# Next.js Router - Getting 404 page not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am new to Next.js, and I am playing around with the router. Some of the pages work, but the dynamic pages don't. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my files structure:

[image]

The Products main page works, but when I am looping through the products and within these products, I have a link like this:

```
<Link href={`/products/${props.product._id}`}>
```

But when I click on any product, I get a 404. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To have a `/products/${props.product._id}` URL, you need to create a `[id]` directory in the `products` folder, in which you add a `page.tsx` (leading to `app/[id]/page.tsx`).

That's because while with the initial [`pages`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, a file creates a route, since Next.js `v13`, and when using the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, a route is created by a folder and a `page.js` is used to render that route, as the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes) shows it:

[image]

Here is (see the last question) where the CLI asks you which one of the routers you want to use:

[image]

Finally, if you are following along a tutorial and want to use the `pages` router, the easiest way is to create a new project and answer the CLI accordingly:

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```