# Dynamic routing problem resulting in error 404

Tags: next.js

I'm building a Next app, and I'm stuck with dynamic routing. I have coding experience in C# and C++, started React/Next a few weeks ago, and I don't know how to fix this routing problem. I read the documentation multiple times, asked ChatGPT, Copilot, ... nothing works.

What am I missing?

This is my testing script:

```
// /app/page.tsx
import Link from 'next/link'
 
function Home() {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link href="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link href="/restaurants">Restaurant</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  )
}
 
export default Home
```

```
// app/restaurants/page.tsx

import Link from 'next/link'
 
function Home() {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link href="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link href="/restaurants/edit/1">Edit Restaurant 1</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link href="/restaurants/edit/2">Edit Restaurant 2</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  )
}
 
export default Home
```

```
// app/restaurants/edit/[id].tsx

"use client";

import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Restaurant() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query

  if (!id) return <p>Chargement...</p>;

  return <p>ID du restaurant : {id}</p>
}
```

- Reading documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes
- Tried to move scrips in app/pages/ : Didn't work
- Tried to move scrips out off app folder, in /pages : Didn't work

---

#### Solution

To have this to work, you have to combine Jimpo26 and Lev-G solution.
Indeed, in documentation it shows that [id] should be a folder, and not a tsx file. My folder now looks like: app/restaurants/[id]/edit/page.tsx
I could have move id after edit, it also works. Next, when your project is structured correctly, you need to apply Leg-G solution, my code was incorrect, I still have to understand why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js Router - Getting 404 page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76467898/next-js-router-getting-404-page-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track!
In order to retrieve the id, use:

```
export default function Restaurant({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  return <div>ID: {params.id}</div>
}
```

Comment: Alone, your solution doesn't work, but with @jimpo26 solution, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since Next.js 13 (in the 'app' directory), there have been changes in how routing works. Instead of naming the file, you should now name the folder with '[id]' to capture dynamic route parameters. Your directory structure should look like this:

```
/app/restaurants/edit/[id]/page.tsx
```

This path matches an url like `http://example.com/restaurants/edit/1234`

Additionally, you can place other files within the '[id]' folder, such as your CSS file or a 'loading.tsx' file, to manage the loading of your UI.

Also, you have a typo in your "use.client", which should look like this: "use client"

Comment: Alone, your solution doesn't work, but with @Lev-G solution, it works.
Thanks.